# running a powershell script on multiple servers using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a situation where I need to run a clean up script written in powershell on Multiple servers , say around 100 windows servers.

How do I accomplish this ?. Doing thru SSH would be cumbersome I believe . I am looking for a better way to configure the Jenkins job to get this task done.

Regards
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Solution**

- Install a Jenkins agent on all your Windows machines
- Affect the same label on all these Windows nodes

Next, you have to install the [Matrix Project plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin) and create a multi-configuration job.

You have to configure the matrix to run your job on the specific label:

[image]

This job will execute your Powershell maintenance script on all the Windows nodes.

Here is a screen copy of a similar maintenance job I'm running on my CentOS nodes:

[image]

**Second solution (not tested)**

The second solution (using OpenSSL) is to execute your Powershell script remotely:
https://hodgkins.io/automating-with-jenkins-and-powershell-on-windows-part-2